# How to make a dumbell plot with ggplot2? Not plotting correctly R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a dumbell plot in ggplot. This is a graph I am trying to recreate in ggplot that I originally made in Tableau.

Although something is wrong with my code - I am trying to follow this tutorial but my data is not being paired properly.  [enter link description here](https://datavizpyr.com/dumbbell-plot-in-r-with-ggplot2/)

Here is my code

```
gnatt <- structure(list(Month = c("JAN 2020", "FEB 2020", "MAR 2020", 
                                  "APR 2020", "MAY 2020", "JUN 2020", "JUL 2020", "AUG 2020", "SEP 2020", 
                                  "OCT 2020", "NOV 2020", "DEC 2020", "JAN 2021", "FEB 2021", "MAR 2021", 
                                  "APR 2021", "MAY 2021", "JUN 2021", "JUL 2021", "JAN 2020", "FEB 2020", 
                                  "MAR 2020", "APR 2020", "MAY 2020", "JUN 2020", "JUL 2020", "AUG 2020", 
                                  "SEP 2020", "OCT 2020", "NOV 2020", "DEC 2020", "JAN 2021", "FEB 2021", 
                                  "MAR 2021", "APR 2021", "MAY 2021", "JUN 2021", "JUL 2021"), 
                        Outcome = c("Additions to Waitlist", "Additions to Waitlist", 
                                    "Additions to Waitlist", "Additions to Waitlist", "Additions to Waitlist", 
                                    "Additions to Waitlist", "Additions to Waitlist", "Additions to Waitlist", 
                                    "Additions to Waitlist", "Additions to Waitlist", "Additions to Waitlist", 
                                    "Additions to Waitlist", "Additions to Waitlist", "Additions to Waitlist", 
                                    "Additions to Waitlist", "Additions to Waitlist", "Additions to Waitlist", 
                                    "Additions to Waitlist", "Additions to Waitlist", "Total Assessments", 
                                    "Total Assessments", "Total Assessments", "Total Assessments", 
                                    "Total Assessments", "Total Assessments", "Total Assessments", 
                                    "Total Assessments", "Total Assessments", "Total Assessments", 
                                    "Total Assessments", "Total Assessments", "Total Assessments", 
                                    "Total Assessments", "Total Assessments", "Total Assessments", 
                                    "Total Assessments", "Total Assessments", "Total Assessments"
                        ), Count = c(222, 199, 160, 30, 98, 127, 75, 121, 164, 140, 
                                     108, 176, 158, 181, 278, 299, 275, 385, 517, 390, 376, 317, 
                                     75, 146, 211, 140, 198, 271, 368, 290, 397, 375, 363, 524, 
                                     441, 509, 697, 961), Percent = c(0.569230769230769, 0.529255319148936, 
                                                                      0.504731861198738, 0.4, 0.671232876712329, 0.601895734597156, 
                                                                      0.535714285714286, 0.611111111111111, 0.605166051660517, 
                                                                      0.380434782608696, 0.372413793103448, 0.443324937027708, 
                                                                      0.421333333333333, 0.49862258953168, 0.530534351145038, 0.678004535147392, 
                                                                      0.54, 0.55, 0.54, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                                                                      NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -38L
                                                                      ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

gnatt <- gnatt %>% 
  mutate(paired = rep(1:(n()/2),each=2),
         Month=factor(Month))

gnatt %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Month, y=Count)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group=paired)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color=Outcome), size = 4) + 
    theme(legend.position = "top")
```

This is the output I am getting.

[image]

My desires output would be something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Month` as the grouping variable:

```r
gnatt %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = Count)) + 
    geom_line(aes(group = Month)) + # Note group here
    geom_point(aes(color = Outcome), size = 4) + 
    theme(legend.position = "top")
```

And to make it even more like the example, you can do the following:

```r
gnatt %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = Count)) + 
    geom_line(aes(group = Month), size = 4, color = "#cccccc") + 
    geom_point(aes(color = Outcome), size = 4) + 
    scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) + ## Custom colors
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.position = "top")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have one follow up question. How can I change the color at geom_point()? I tried geom_point(aes(group=c("red","blue"), size = 4) but i got an Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (20): colour

Comment: I just added a line that changes the colors used. For future reference, you do not want to use `aes()`, that changes the *mapping* -- that is, which variables to use to identify that certain points should have colors different from one another. You want to use `scale_color` to change the *specific* colors.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried to reproduce it as close as I can:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- dat |>
  rename_with(tolower) |>
  mutate(
    date  = as.Date(
      gsub(
        '(\\w{3})\\s(\\d{4})', 
        '\\1 01 \\2', 
        stringr::str_to_sentence(month)
      ),
      '%b %d %Y'
    ),
    percent = ifelse(
        !is.na(percent), 
        sprintf('(%d %s)', round(percent * 100), '%'),
        NA_character_
    ), 
    month   = NULL
  ) 

sgm <- pivot_wider(
  dat, 
  id_cols     = date, 
  names_from  = 'outcome', 
  values_from = 'count'
  ) |>
  setNames(c('date', 'y', 'yend'))

ggplot(data = sgm) +
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = date, xend = date, y = y, yend = yend), 
    size = 7, 
    colour = 'grey90'
    ) +
  geom_point(
    data    = dat, 
    mapping = aes(x = date, y = count, colour = outcome), 
    size    = 7
    ) + 
  geom_text(
    mapping = aes(x = date, y = y, label = y), 
    nudge_y = -30, 
    size    = 3.5
    ) +
  geom_text(
    mapping = aes(x = date, y = yend, label = yend), 
    nudge_y = 30, 
    size    = 3.5
    ) +
  geom_text(
    data    = dat, 
    mapping = aes(x = date, y = count, label = percent), 
    nudge_y = -55, size = 3.5, colour = 'gray50'
    ) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 month', date_labels = '%b %y') +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1000, by = 50)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('skyblue', 'coral')) +
  ggthemes::theme_clean() +
  theme(
    legend.position   = 'bottom',
    legend.title      = element_blank(), 
    legend.background = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x      = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y      = element_blank(),
    axis.line.x       = element_line(colour = 'gray50'),
    axis.line.y       = element_line(colour = 'gray50'),
    axis.ticks        = element_line(colour = 'gray50'), 
    axis.text         = element_text(colour = 'gray50')
  )
```

[image: desired graphical output]